# Get relationship data with laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 tables clients and maintenance_packages and I'm trying to list all clients and their maintenance package but keep getting the following error.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'maintenance_packages.client_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `maintenance_packages` where `maintenance_packages`.`client_id` = 2 and `maintenance_packages`.`client_id` is not null limit 1)
```

I'm guessing it the way I've set up the relationships? Below is my DB Migrations, Models & Controller.

Clients DB

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clients', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 55);
        $table->string('email', 100);
        $table->integer('maintenance_id')->unsigned();
    });
}
```

Maintenance DB

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('maintenance_packages', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 55);
        $table->integer('hours');
        $table->decimal('price');
    });
}
```

Client Model

```
namespace App;
use App\MaintenancePackage;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model 
{

    protected $table = 'clients';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function maintenance()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(MaintenancePackage::class);
    }

}
```

Maintenance Model

```
namespace App;
use App\Client;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MaintenancePackage extends Model 
{

    protected $table = 'maintenance_packages';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
  {
      $clients = Client::with('maintenance')->get();
      return view('clients.index', compact('clients', 'maintenance'));
  }
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: as your database structure, every `client` belongsToOne `package`...

Comment: @tuytoosh i've change hasOne to belongsToOne but now I get Call to undefined relationship [maintenance] on model [App\Client].

Plus the client doesn't belong to a package a package belongs to the client and the packages have many clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Client Model replace

```
public function maintenance()
{
    return $this->hasOne(MaintenancePackage::class);
}
```

with

```
public function maintenance()
{
    return $this->BelongsTo(MaintenancePackage::class, 'maintenance_id');
}
```

Now In your Maintenance Model replace

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}
```

with

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Client::class, 'maintenance_id');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had just figured it out and was writing a reply when I saw this pop up.